# Django choices and dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have code

```
JOBS = 1
CATEGORY_CHOICES = ((JOBS, "Jobs"),)
```

And code in the model

```
category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=JOBS)
```

Instead of "jobs" I want to add a dictionary and have access to it in the template. For example

```
JOBS = 1
CATEGORY_CHOICES = ((JOBS, {'title':"Jobs",'icon':"fa fa-briefcase",'slug':"jobs"}),)
```

But instead I get the following

[image]

How to add the dictionary into the choices?
I was able to create a model, which would be set up: title and icon. But instead, I decided to create a choice. Title I can add, but for the selected item to set the icon?

Comment: what does it mean ` JOBS=1`

Comment: be clear what you want to do

Comment: @HishamKaram I was able to create a model, which would be set up: title and icon. But instead, I decided to create a choice. Title I can add, but for the selected item to set the icon?

Comment: if you want to make choices for example use `tuple(x for x in zip(range(10),string.ascii_letters))` will produce some thing like this `((0, 'a'),
 (1, 'b'),
 (2, 'c'),
 (3, 'd'),
 (4, 'e'),
 (5, 'f'),
 (6, 'g'),
 (7, 'h'),
 (8, 'i'),
 (9, 'j'))`

Comment: @HishamKaram I create my tuple. Just in the example above, there is one choice. My problem is that I want to add a field

Comment: Don't use the comments to answer the question. Write a real answer!

Comment: one choice !!! what appear to user to choose and what do tou want to save in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would comment, but sadly not enough rep. The way [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) is setup, it displays the dictionary value and returns the dictionary key.

What it seems you want to do is have that key determine the results of several other values. What you should do then is in whatever view you submit that form to, set those other values based on the key returned by your IntegerField.

In other words:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = ((1, 'Jobs'),(2, 'Cities'),)
```

Then later in the class or view that this form is submitted to:

```
if CATEGORY_CHOICES  == 1:
    title = 'Jobs'
    icon = 'fa fa-briefcase'
    slug = 'jobs'
elif CATEGORY_CHOICES == 2:
    title = 'Cities'
`   icon = 'fa fa-city'
    slug = 'cities'
```

Comment: Hi Greg, please don't use answers as comments. Please modify your answer if you have a potential solution to the question.

Comment: I think I gave a solution by setting the parameters later by using the key. You gave a better one though.

Comment: @GregSchmit Thank you. I have no choice but to use this kind of dependency.

Comment: Not a problem, but I have to give Soviut credit for providing an objectively better answer in terms of rigor. My way is slightly hacky.

Answer (score 3):

Choices in Django models are `(key, value)` tuples. The key is what's meant to be stored in the model's field when saved and the value is meant to be what's displayed as an option. You can't simply jam a dictionary into the value.

For example, the below choices would store `human` in the database and display `Humans` in a select field.

```
species = [
    ('human', 'Humans'),
    ('reptile', 'Reptiles'),
    ('cylons', 'Aliens'),
]
```

Instead, you need to restructure how your model your data. You should create a separate `Category` model that represents the choices which will contain fields for a slug, icon and title.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    slug  = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField()
    icon  = models.CharField()
```

You then point your current model at the `Category` model using a `ForeignKey()`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Finally, you can use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) when rendering the form to render the related category models (related across the foreign key) as choices in a list. If you use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/), all foreign keys will be represented as [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)s by default.

Comment: But if I want: (key, {"key": "value", "key": value}) ?

Comment: You can't. I just explained it. That's not how relational databases work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to create a list outside of the database, but need more fields. I'll think how to implement it differently.

Comment: @alexander you haven't provided any reason why you want to do that. Why break a very well established convention that works?

Comment: Because there is a hard choice. Either that, or that. It makes no sense to use a database.

Comment: It makes plenty of sense, hence why it's a common enough pattern for django to include facilities to easily do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Choices` class form `django_model_helpers` app.
https://github.com/rewardz/django_model_helpers

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = Choices(
     {"jobs": {'id': 1, 'display': 'Jobs', 'icon':"fa fa-briefcase",'slug':"jobs"}
)
```

Then in your model

```
category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES(), default=CATEGORY_CHOICES.jobs)
```

Now to access icon from code:

```
icon = CATEGORY_CHOICES.get_value(my_inst.category, "icon")
slug = CATEGORY_CHOICES.get_value(my_inst.category, "slug")
```